# WPF DataGrid row enter and row leave events

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I work on a window that has a DataGrid which is bound to an observable collection that holds items that originate from a database table. I want to remember the original item when a row in the grid is entered and I want to commit the added or updated item to the database when the row in the grid is left. I need original and modified values to find out what has changed.

Basically I want to implement the same behavior like in Visual Studio or SQL Developer Studio when you enter data in a data table.

Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks.

In my current implementation I do not get the original values of the item when a field is changed and also the OnItemChanged is called for each changed field and I would prefer to commit the whole row at once.

Here is my view:

```
<Window x:Class="TourMan.Views.EditPersonsView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Persons">
   <Grid>
       <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" 
        RowBackground="LightGoldenrodYellow" AlternatingRowBackground="PaleGoldenrod" AlternationCount="2"
            CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" >
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Width ="100" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Address" Width ="250" Binding="{Binding Addresses}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
       </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the view model:

```
class EditPersonsViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Person> Persons { get;  }

    public EditPersonsViewModel()
    {
        Persons = Engine.Instance().GetPersons();
        foreach (var person in Persons)
        {
            person.PropertyChanged += OnItemChanged;
        }
        Persons.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
    }

    private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add && e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in e.NewItems)
            {
                Engine.Instance().AddPerson((Person)item);
                ((Person)item).PropertyChanged += OnItemChanged;
            }
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove && e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (var item in e.OldItems)
            {
                Engine.Instance().DeletePerson(((Field)item));
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnItemChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Engine.Instance().UpdatePerson((Person)sender, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long and painful search I found the solution here https://www.codeproject.com/kb/wpf/wpfdatagridexamples.aspx and it is really cool so I would like to share it.

The items in the collection need to implement IEditableObject. Then the datagrid will call BeginEdit() when row edit starts and EndEdit() when the edit is ended. See all the detais in this great article.